# Enabling and disabling command in JavaScript discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make an automemes command, I can get it to send memes automatically, but when I try to disable it, it sends the `Automemes disabled!` command, but it still sends them. Here's the code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const fetch = (...args) => import("node-fetch").then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("automemes")
    .setDescription("Sends random memes every 5 minutes (from r/memes)")
    .addBooleanOption(option =>
        option.setName("enabled")
        .setDescription("Set the automemes to on/off")
        .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(client, interaction, Discord) {

        let isEnabled = interaction.options.get("enabled").value;

        switch (isEnabled) {

            case true: interaction.reply("Automemes enabled! " + ENV.CATKISS)
            
            break;

            case false: isEnabled = false;

            break;
        }

        async function sendMemes() {

                fetch("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/memes")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(async json => {
                    
                    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(json.title)
                    .setImage(json.url)
        
                    if (Embed.title.length > 256) return;

                    await interaction.channel.send({embeds: [Embed]});
                });
        }

        isEnabled? setInterval(() => sendMemes(), 10000) : interaction.reply("Automemes disabled! " + ENV.CATKISS);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you cleared the interval (check out [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)). Without that, it will run forever. Also, that `switch` statement is absolutely unnecessary. You check the variable's boolean value and if it's `false`, you update the variable to the same `false` value again.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to accomplish but, as stated above by @Zsolt Meszaros, your interval is never getting cleared. That means that if that interval gets activated once, it will continue perpetually until your bot shuts down. Try declaring your interval as a constant so you can enable and disable it however you choose.

```
      const myInterval = setInterval(sendMemes, 10000) //declaring interval
      async fucntion startInterval() {
        myInterval; //function to start interval
      }
      async function disableInterval() {
        clearInterval(myInterval); //function to clear interval
        interaction.reply(interaction.reply("Automemes disabled! " + ENV.CATKISS));
      }
        isEnabled? startInterval() : disableInterval(); //added starter and stopper functions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I dind't know about clearInterval, however, I tried like you suggested but it still sends memes when I try to disable and it still sends me the disabled message, so the function gets executed, but the interval does not stop :(

Comment: I was afraid that'd happen. It's most likely because its creating different instances of the repeating interval each time you do the slash command. I tried my solution on a test in just a static javascript file and it worked for enabling and disabling an interval. So if you'd like to maintain this implementation, consider declaring your interval in a class that will not be instatiated every time the execute() function is called. A hacky solution is to pass in the interval in the execute(interaction, myInterval) from the index.js for this command call only. Try and see if that works.

Comment: A more permanent and scalable solution to this particular issue would be some sort of state management. I'm not familiar with their libraries, but I'm sure some of the youtube/music discord bots require this to properly pause and play their content. Maybe check them out for some inspiration if you decide to keep scaling your bot.

Comment: Will try! Thank you for your help!